# Query SQL image data type and output to string

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing code to export a SQL table (which contains 2 text/int fields, and an image type field) to a csv file.  Everything works, except I can't get the image file to be successfully written to a string.  Here is my current code for this part:

```
string selectDocRows = "SELECT ID,Name FROM Documents WHERE ID=" + DocumentID;
SqlCommand selectFileData = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileData FROM Documents WHERE ID=" + DocumentID,SQLConnection);
using (SqlDataAdapter DocAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectDocRows, SQLConnection))
{
    using (DataTable DocTable = new DataTable("DocumentResults"))
    {
        DocAdapter.Fill(DocTable);

        foreach (DataRow row in DocTable.Rows)
        {
            string DocRow = string.Format("{0},{1},", row[0], row[1]);
            byte[] DocPDF = (byte[])selectFileData.ExecuteScalar() ;
            CSVText.AppendLine(DocRow + DocPDF);
        }
    }
}
```

The result that returns for the byte[] called DocPDF is:

1,ChatLog Meet Now 2016_12_13 12_26.pdf,System.Byte[]

> 3 columns: index, filename, and file content

But instead of genuine file content, I just get "System.Byte[]"

I get the same results when doing a single sql query and converting that 3rd column to a string.  I need (and would expect) the 127,000 characters that I see in my sql query.  Instead I just get "System.Byte[]"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `byte[]` to a string

> string foo = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(DocPDF);

and then write this to the CSV

> CSVText.AppendLine(DocRow + "," + foo);

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code in depth - assuming that DocPDF contains an array of bytes, and that you're writing to a text file.. convert the data to Base64.

string docRow = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", ... ,..., Convert.ToBase64String(docPDF));